# redirect users to error page upon accessing a path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have an .htaccess on my "app" folder and what I want is that if any user attempts to access that directory, then they will be redirected to the error page. This is what's inside the .htaccess:

my full directory is: Rummage/app/view/errors/404.php
my .htaccess is inside app folder: Rummage/app/.htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /pages/errors/404.php
```

It doesn't seem to work. I also have another .htaccess on my Rummage/public which is a clean url .htaccess. It works but the error .htaccess is not working on app folder.

Comment: What is your `DocumentRoot` and what is full URL for `404.php`?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the noob question, but what do you mean by DocumentRoot?

Comment: `DocumentRoot` is your site root path

Comment: htdocs/Rummage/ is that it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `/app/.htaccess`
2. Place this rule in site root `.htaccess`

**root .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+app/[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /app/view/errors/404.php [L,R=404]
```